# How to create "No Activate" form in Firemonkey

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, c++builder, firemonkey

In XCode by adding these methods to your NSView subclass can prevent the window from becoming active when clicking on it:

```c
- (BOOL)shouldDelayWindowOrderingForEvent:(NSEvent )theEvent {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent )theEvent {
    return YES; 
}
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent )theEvent {
    [[[NSApp]] preventWindowOrdering]; 
}
```

In Windows platform It is done by this simple code:

```cpp
HWND hWnd = FindWindowW((String("FM") + fmxForm->ClassName()).c_str(), 
    fmxForm->Caption.c_str());

SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,
    GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
```

How can I subclass NSView to prevent my FMX TForm becoming active when clicking on it?

How can I create "**No Activate**" form in *firemonkey*?

Comment: Not sure if it applies to Firemonkey as well, or if it answers your question properly, but you might want to have a look at this example: http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/ex_noactivate.htm

Comment: Thankyou, but it is only for Windows and the easier way is my solution described above by "SetWindowLong", The question is about MacOS.

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048346/how-embed-a-firemonkey-form-inside-a-control

Comment: Devon: How this link could help me?

Comment: Thanks to WBAR, it is second bounty!

Comment: No problem but still You cannot get an answer :/

Comment: Put your code in a timer - so the window stays always deactivated- hope this is applicable in firemonkey!

Comment: I requested a new feature on QualityCentral, please rate it:http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=116611

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible using **NSPanel** with **NSNonactivatingPanelMask** flag. The NSView of fmx form should become child of NSPanel. I have written a helper class which works for both Windows and Mac platforms (**Works on XE4**):

```
unit NoActivateForm;

interface

uses Fmx.Forms, Fmx.Types
{$IFDEF POSIX}
    , Macapi.AppKit
{$ENDIF}
    ;

type TNoActivateForm = class
private
    form: TForm;
{$IFDEF POSIX}
    panel: NSPanel;
    timer: TTimer;  // for simulating mouse hover event
{$ENDIF}
    procedure SetPosition(const x, y: Integer);
    procedure GetPosition(var x, y: Integer);
    procedure SetDimensions(const width, height: Integer);
    procedure SetLeft(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetTop(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetHeight(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetWidth(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetVisible(const Value: Boolean);
    function GetLeft: Integer;
    function GetTop: Integer;
    function GetHeight: Integer;
    function GetWidth: Integer;
    function GetVisible: Boolean;
{$IFDEF POSIX}
    procedure OnTimer(Sender: TObject);
{$ENDIF}
public
    constructor Create(AForm: TForm);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Left: Integer read GetLeft write SetLeft;
    property Top: Integer read GetTop write SetTop;
    property Height: Integer read GetHeight write SetHeight;
    property Width: Integer read GetWidth write SetWidth;
    property Visible: Boolean read GetVisible write SetVisible;
end;

implementation
uses
    Classes, System.Types
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    , Winapi.Windows;
{$ELSE}
    , Macapi.CocoaTypes, FMX.Platform.Mac, Macapi.CoreGraphics, Macapi.CoreFoundation;
{$ENDIF}

constructor TNoActivateForm.Create(AForm: TForm);
{$IFDEF POSIX}
var
    rect: NSRect;
    bounds: CGRect;
    window: NSWindow;
    style: integer;
    panelCount: integer;
begin
    form := AForm;
    form.Visible := false;
    bounds := CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID);
    rect := MakeNSRect(form.Left, bounds.size.height - form.Top - form.Height,
        form.ClientWidth, form.ClientHeight);
    style := NSNonactivatingPanelMask;
    style := style or NSHUDWindowMask;
    panel := TNSPanel.Wrap(
        TNSPanel.Alloc.initWithContentRect(rect, style, NSBackingStoreBuffered,
        true));
    panel.setFloatingPanel(true);
    //panel.setHasShadow(false); optional
    window := WindowHandleToPlatform(form.Handle).Wnd;

    panel.setContentView(TNSView.Wrap(window.contentView));
    TNSView.Wrap(window.contentView).retain;

    timer := TTimer.Create(form.Owner);
    timer.OnTimer := OnTimer;
    timer.Interval := 50;
end;
{$ELSE}
var hWin: HWND;
begin
    form := AForm;
    form.TopMost := true;
    hWin := FindWindow(PWideChar('FM' + form.ClassName), PWideChar(form.Caption));
    if hWin <> 0 then
        SetWindowLong(hWin, GWL_EXSTYLE,
            GetWindowLong(hWin, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
end;
{$ENDIF}

destructor TNoActivateForm.Destroy;
{$IFDEF POSIX}
begin
    panel.release;
end;
{$ELSE}
begin
end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure TNoActivateForm.SetPosition(const x, y: Integer);
{$IFDEF POSIX}
var point: NSPoint;
    screen: CGRect;
begin
    screen := CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID);
    point.x := x;
    point.y := round(screen.size.height) - y - form.height;
    panel.setFrameOrigin(point);
end;
{$ELSE}
begin
    form.Left := x;
    form.Top := y;
end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure TNoActivateForm.GetPosition(var x, y: Integer);
{$IFDEF POSIX}
var screen: CGRect;
begin
    screen := CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID);
    x := round(panel.frame.origin.x);
    y := round(screen.size.height - panel.frame.origin.y - panel.frame.size.height);
end;
{$ELSE}
begin
    x := form.Left;
    y := form.Top;
end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure TNoActivateForm.SetDimensions(const width, height: Integer);
{$IFDEF POSIX}
var size: NSSize;
begin
    size.width := width;
    size.height := height;
    panel.setContentSize(size);
end;
{$ELSE}
begin
    form.width := width;
    form.height := height;
end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure TNoActivateForm.SetLeft(const Value: Integer);
begin
    SetPosition(Value, Top);
end;

procedure TNoActivateForm.SetTop(const Value: Integer);
begin
    SetPosition(Left, Value);
end;

procedure TNoActivateForm.SetHeight(const Value: Integer);
begin
    SetDimensions(Width, Value);
end;

procedure TNoActivateForm.SetWidth(const Value: Integer);
begin
    SetDimensions(Value, Height);
end;

procedure TNoActivateForm.SetVisible(const Value: Boolean);
begin
{$IFDEF POSIX}
    panel.setIsVisible(Value);
{$ELSE}
    form.visible := Value;
{$ENDIF}
end;

function TNoActivateForm.GetLeft: Integer;
var x, y: Integer;
begin
    GetPosition(x, y);
    result := x;
end;

function TNoActivateForm.GetTop: Integer;
var x, y: Integer;
begin
    GetPosition(x, y);
    result := y;
end;

function TNoActivateForm.GetHeight: Integer;
begin
{$IFDEF POSIX}
    result := round(panel.frame.size.height);
{$ELSE}
    result := form.Height;
{$ENDIF}
end;

function TNoActivateForm.GetWidth: Integer;
begin
{$IFDEF POSIX}
    result := round(panel.frame.size.width);
{$ELSE}
    result := form.Width;
{$ENDIF}
end;

function TNoActivateForm.GetVisible: Boolean;
begin
{$IFDEF POSIX}
    result := panel.isVisible();
{$ELSE}
    result := form.visible;
{$ENDIF}
end;

{$IFDEF POSIX}
procedure TNoActivateForm.OnTimer(Sender: TObject);
var event: CGEventRef;
    point: CGPoint;
    form_rect: TRectF;
    client_point, mouse_loc: TPointF;
    shift: TShiftState;
begin
    event := CGEventCreate(nil);
    point := CGEventGetLocation(event);
    CFRelease(event);
    mouse_loc.SetLocation(point.x, point.y);
    if Visible = true then
    begin
        form_rect := RectF(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height);
        client_point.X := mouse_loc.X - Left;
        client_point.Y := mouse_loc.y - Top;
        if PtInRect(form_rect, client_point) then
            form.MouseMove(shift, client_point.x, client_point.y)
        else
            form.MouseLeave();
    end;
end;
{$ENDIF}

end.
```

Usage of above unit:

```cpp
TNoActivateForm *naKeyboard; // global scope    
void __fastcall TfrmKeyboard::TfrmKeyboard(TObject *Sender)
{
    naKeyboard = new TNoActivateForm(frmKeyboard); // frmKeyboard is a normal fmx form
    naKeyboard->Visible = true;
}
```

If frmKeyboard is your Main Form then do not put above code in form constructor, It is recommended to put it in OnShow.

[image]

**Note**: WindowHandleToPlatform doesn't seem to exist in XE3 so that line can be replaced with

```
window := NSWindow(NSWindowFromObjC(FmxHandleToObjC(Form.Handle)));
```

Comment: Thanks for  great solution - windowhandletoplatform doesn't seem to exist in XE3 so that line can be replaced with window:=NSWindow(NSWindowFromObjC(FmxHandleToObjC(Form.Handle)));

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the forms mouse handling to prevent it being focused. Assuming your form is called myform:

```
uses fmx.platform.mac, macapi.appkit;
.
.
Var nswin:nswindow;
.
.  
NSWin:= NSWindow(NSWindowFromObjC(FmxHandleToObjC(myform.Handle))); { get the NSWindow }
NSWin.setIgnoresMouseEvents(true);                                 { ignore mouse events }
NSWin.setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents(false);
```

There is a slight problem in that it doesn't stop a right mouse click. If that's a problem, you will have to respond to the mousedown event in the form and call the main forms mousedown so it doesn't lose the mouse event.  Since the right mouse down will then capture the mouse events, you also then need to respond to mouse move and mouse up events too - forwarding them to your main form. Although it captures the mouse on right click, it will still not focus the form.

Dave Peters
DP Software

Comment: Incorrect, does not work. The form changes keyboard focus on click.

Comment: Well its not getting focus but what happens is that any mouse clicks go through the form to whatever is beneath it. If you can arrange that the non focus form has the TopMost property set and only a blank part of your own main form is ever below it, then it will work. If you have any main form controls underneath the window then they will get focus when you mouse click as the non-focus window behaves like it is not there. Similarly if the window is placed over the desktop then the desktop gets the mouse click and your application loses focus.

Comment: Note that I need mouse events. I can not ignore mouse events. I want to click on a button, also I want to have firemonkey animations when mouse pointer enters on a control. Assume that I want to create a virtual keyboard, foreground application is (for example) TextEdit. When I click on a button on my fmx form, an keyboard event will be generated and a character will be typed.