# On screen keyboard with firemonkey [Mac]

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have written an **On Screen Keyboard** using firemonkey.

[image]

I simulate key events with this code:

```cpp
void kbdEvent(unsigned int key, int modifiers)
{
    ::CGEventSourceRef source =
        CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
    ::CGEventRef keyDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source,
        (::CGKeyCode)key, true);
    ::CGEventRef keyUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (::CGKeyCode)key,
        false);
    CGEventSetFlags(keyDown, modifiers);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, keyDown);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, keyUp);
    CFRelease(keyUp);
    CFRelease(keyDown);
    CFRelease(source);
}
```

The problem is that when I press a key then my form receives focus and the generated event is not received by target app. If I put the following code in a timer there is no problem and the 'a' will typed in any editable target:

```
kbdEvent(kVK_ANSI_A, 0);
```

How can I do it without receive focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to make an **OSK** is a *No Activate Form*. See the most popular firemonkey [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769064/how-to-create-no-activate-form-in-firemonkey).
A "No Activate" window does not become the foreground window when the user clicks it. The system does not bring this window to the foreground when the user minimizes or closes the foreground window.